# Which is the best way to assign values to a const depending on a condition?

Tags: javascript, constants

I want to assign a value to a const based on the website language, there are 15 cases, so I end up with a function like this:

```
      function messageLang() {
    if (language === 'en') {
      return 'Message in English'
    } else if (language === 'fr') {
      return 'Message in French'
    } else if (language === 'es') {
      return 'Message in Spanish'
    } (...etc)
  }

const msgLang = messageLang()
```

I have to do this for a title, a subtitle, and a message, so I have created 3 similar functions.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object literal for that:

```
const msgLang = {
    en: 'Message in English',
    fr: 'Message in French',
    es: 'Message in Spanish',
    /* etc */
}[language];
```

Where `language` is the actual language code (e.g. "es").

When you have more such phrases to translate, then create an object with all those:

```js
let phrases = {
    welcome: {
        en: "Welcome",
        fr: "Bienvenu",
        es: "Bienvenido",
    },
    bye: {
        en: "Bye",
        fr: "Au revoir",
        es: "Adiós"
    }
}

let language = "es";
console.log(phrases.welcome[language]);
console.log(phrases.bye[language]);
```

Comment: Many thanks trincot, really good explanation.